# SQL Inner Join. ON condition vs WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am busy converting a query using the old style syntax to the new join syntax. The essence of my query is as follows :

Original Query

```
SELECT i.*  
FROM 
  InterestRunDailySum i, 
  InterestRunDetail ird, 
  InterestPayments p
WHERE 
   p.IntrPayCode = 187
   AND i.IntRunCode = p.IntRunCode AND i.ClientCode = p.ClientCode
   AND ird.IntRunCode = p.IntRunCode AND ird.ClientCode = p.ClientCode
```

New Query

```
SELECT  i.*
  FROM InterestPayments p
    INNER JOIN InterestRunDailySum i 
      ON (i.IntRunCode = p.IntRunCode AND i.ClientCode = p.ClientCode)
    INNER JOIN InterestRunDetail ird 
      ON (ird.IntRunCode = p.IntRunCode AND ird.IntRunCode = p.IntRunCode)
  WHERE 
    p.IntrPayCode = 187
```

In this example, "Original Query" returns 46 rows, where "New Query" returns over 800

Can someone explain the difference to me? I would have assumed that these queries are identical.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is with your join to `InterestRunDetail`.  You are joining on `IntRunCode` twice.

The correct query should be:

```
SELECT  i.*
  FROM InterestPayments p
    INNER JOIN InterestRunDailySum i 
      ON (i.IntRunCode = p.IntRunCode AND i.ClientCode = p.ClientCode)
    INNER JOIN InterestRunDetail ird 
      ON (ird.IntRunCode = p.IntRunCode AND ird.ClientCode = p.ClientCode)
  WHERE 
    p.IntrPayCode = 187
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin, I feel like a fool for not spotting that!!

Comment: It happens to all of us.  :-)

Answer (score 6):

The "new query" is the one compatible with the current ANSI SQL standard for JOINs.

Also, I find query #2 much **cleaner**:

- you are almost forced to think about and specify the **join condition(s)** between two tables - you will not accidentally have cartesian products in your query. If you happen to list ten tables, but only six join conditions in your `WHERE` clause - you'll get **a lot more** data back than expected!
- your `WHERE` clause isn't cluttered with join conditions and thus it's cleaner, less messy, easier to read and understand
- the **type** of your JOIN (whether `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`) is typically a lot easier to see - since you spell it out. With the "old-style" syntax, the difference between those join types is rather hard to see, buried somewhere in your lots of `WHERE` criteria.....

Functionally, the two are identical - #1 might be deprecated sooner or later by some query engines.

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent [Bad Habits to Kick - using old-style JOIN syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) blog post for more info - and while you're at it - read **all** "bad habits to kick" posts - all very much worth it!

Comment: Good answer - but his queries aren't actually identical - it looks like it was just a typo ;-)